# MVC Core 2.1 Directory Browser some files not shown

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC core application that has some folders that allow browsing.
I have used the UseDirectoryBrowser in order to map shared folders and they do appear to be browsable, the problem is that not all files are shown (specifically the files with MSI extensions).
The files do appear when they first uploaded but then disappear after a refresh of page.
We migrated to azure recently and same code was previously used on different hosting provider where we did not ever had same problems.

Is there something i could look into ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot repro your issue, but here is what I did in my side which works well. You can compare with your code:

In Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices method, add this line of code `services.AddDirectoryBrowser()`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
    }
```

In Startup.cs -> Configure method, add `app.UseDirectoryBrowser(xxx)`:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images")),
            RequestPath = "/MyImages"
        });

        app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images")),
            RequestPath = "/MyImages"
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

After publish to azure, I can see all the files in images directory, even refresh many times:

[image]

Comment: this is not different with what i am doing, i will try to play around with configuration and see if it can be resolved, the funny thing is that the files are downloaded normally although not listed by directory browser.

Comment: @NullReference, is it something with your browser, can you use other browser for test? And for narrowing down this issue, can you just create a new web project, and publish to azure to see if it still occurs.

Comment: so i tried multiple changes but no luck, what i notice is that its not the file extension its the amount of files shown, basically the browser will show all sub directories and just one file in the directory (if other directories exist in folder) or zero files if there are no sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem will only go away if PhysicalFileProvider receives an ExclusionFilters parameter equal to None. This makes the problem go away. Just in case some one else encounters it.